# Tangle current src block and process it in another

Tags: org-babel, tangle

How can I run the `test` src block ****without leaving the `code` src block****?

Currently I must leave `code`, goto `test`, hit  <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> , go back to continue work on `code`

```
#+NAME: code
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :tangle /tmp/foo.sh
foo="bar"
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: test
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :var DUMMY=(progn (org-babel-goto-named-src-block "code") (org-babel-tangle '(4))) :results output
echo "Process tests on this file":
cat /tmp/foo.sh
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: Process tests on this file:
: foo="bar"
```

Using the promising looking `#+begin_src sh :tangle /tmp/foo.sh :var DUMMY=(progn (org-babel-goto-named-src-block "test") (org-babel-execute-src-block))`  on the `code` src block returns `Lisp nesting exceeds ‘max-lisp-eval-depth’`

---

Org mode version 9.4.5

Comment: with org 9.4.6 your code works fine for me.

Comment: @JohnKitchin John you mean you're able to hit `C-c C-C` in the `code` block to tangle itself to `foo.sh` and `test` is run subsequently? Offtopic: I read your org mode docstring testing blogpost since this current question relates to pytest with org babel

Comment: Yes, CcCc in the test block tangles the “code” block and runs the tangled file for me.

Comment: I **must** remain on the current line in the `code` block. **No** back and forth switching to the the `test` block.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it with babel: do it in lisp - define a function to do what you want and bind it to a key. You can then execute the function from anywhere using that key. Something like this:

```el
#+begin_src elisp
(defun ndk/org-babel-evaluate-test-block-from-code-block ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (org-babel-goto-named-src-block "code")
    (org-babel-execute-src-block)
    (org-babel-goto-named-src-block "test")
    (org-babel-execute-src-block)))

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c z") #'ndk/org-babel-evaluate-test-block-from-code-block)
#+end_src
```

Pressing `C-c z` from anywhere in the buffer will do the evaluations and leave `point` unchanged. If you do it from the code block, that's where you will remain.

Comment: It probably doesn't hurt but I don't think the nested `save-excursion` is needed: I should have removed it when I modified the function to work from anywhere without moving `point`. I'll test without it and edit the answer.

Comment: Tested and edited the answer to remove the nested `save-excursion`.